# R shiny table with plots inside the table

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, shinydashboard

I'm developing an R shiny app and ideally I would need to do precisely what is done here:
[image]

More specifically, I have dataframe with stocks open, close, high, low data and I would need to replicate what's displayed in the attached image in column "Range".
I understand I should attach some code, but the truth here, I can't find anything close to what I'm asking online.
A sample dataframe would be:

```
df = data.frame(STOCK=c("IBM","MSFT","FB"),  OPEN=c(100,90, 80), CLOSE=c(102, 85, 82), LOW=c(99,81,78), HIGH=c(105, 91, 88))
```

Then, I have no idea of what to do from here. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom-rendering follow this guide

https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#custom-rendering-1

```
library(dplyr)
library(sparkline)

data <- chickwts %>%
  group_by(feed) %>%
  summarise(weight = list(weight)) %>%
  mutate(boxplot = NA, sparkline = NA)

reactable(data, columns = list(
  weight = colDef(cell = function(values) {
    sparkline(values, type = "bar", chartRangeMin = 0, chartRangeMax = max(chickwts$weight))
  }),
  boxplot = colDef(cell = function(value, index) {
    sparkline(data$weight[[index]], type = "box")
  }),
  sparkline = colDef(cell = function(value, index) {
    sparkline(data$weight[[index]])
  })
))
```